# Increase XSL stack size in MSXML

Tags: xslt, recursion, stack, overflow, msxml

In the XSL processor in MSXML, I'm getting an error while running a recursive template on a "larger" dataset.  The recursion terminates correctly, and works fine for "smaller" datasets as well, so I know it's not an infinite loop.  Is there a way to jack up the stack size somewhat as a quick fix, as opposed to recoding to shoot for lower stack usage (which is probably a useful longer term goal).

```
msxml3.dll error '80004005'  The XSL processor stack has overflowed - probable cause is infinite template recursion.
```

Thank you, Stack overflow readers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such setting or property and the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx only has some security related properties like `MaxElementDepth` and `MaxXMLSize` but no settings on the XSLT processor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

So based on that it looks as you need to rewrite your code and use techniques like divide and conquer to reduce recursion depth.

Comment: ... or switch to an XSLT processor that implements tail call optimization.